# Count rows that fall between two times

Tags: google-sheets

Looking to get the count of rows that fall within a certain hour of the day.

I can perform `IF` statements against the times, but not `COUNTIF(S)`...

So far I have tried:

```
=countifs(timevalue(A2:A),">=b2",timevalue(A2:A),"<=c2")
```

And even tried hard coding the times in, e.g.:

```
=countifs(timevalue(A2:A),">=05:00:00",timevalue(A2:A),"<=05:59:59")
```

Also not really sure if/why `TIMEVALUE` is needed, since it seems I am working with actual datetime cells... however it seemed to help on the `IF` statements.

Here is my sample spreadsheet showing data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gEmuc00W1sY_TClx1uR9lqYRRtsHzzWyQvO8o3G8epE/edit#gid=255648219

Comment: I also found this blog post (https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/countifs-in-a-time-range-in-google-sheets/) which seemed to indicate that I was on the right track, but again this doesn't seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 1):

You want to count of the rows where the time value in Column A falls within the "START" and "END" values in Column B and C

Try `=query(A2:C22,"select COUNT(A) where  timeofday '"&TEXT(A2,"HH:mm:ss")&"'>= B and  C>= timeofday '"&TEXT(A2,"HH:mm:ss")&"'")`

- `timeofday` is a data type supported by query.
- Columns B and C are already formatted for time.
- Column A has a datetime value and needs to be recast as time. `TEXT(A2,"HH:mm:ss")` converts the value in Column A number into text according to the specified format.